# PIC24 - testing I2C module dead/alive

Tags: pic, i2c

I got PIC24FJ192GB106 (64 pin package) and I cannot get the I2C module working at all. What is the easiest and most straight forward way of testing, whether the module is OK?

I am using I2C1 module, (SCL1 - pin 44, SDA1 - pin 43).

```
BRG register = 39; // 100 kHz for Fosc = 8 MHz

// Control register
    I2C1CONbits.I2CEN = 1;    
    I2C1CONbits.I2CSIDL = 0;   
    I2C1CONbits.SCLREL = 1; 
    I2C1CONbits.IPMIEN = 0;   
    I2C1CONbits.A10M = 0;    
    I2C1CONbits.DISSLW = 1;   
    I2C1CONbits.SMEN = 0;     
    I2C1CONbits.GCEN = 0;   
    I2C1CONbits.STREN = 0;   
    I2C1CONbits.ACKDT = 0;    
    I2C1CONbits.ACKEN = 0;   
    I2C1CONbits.RCEN = 0;   
    I2C1CONbits.PEN = 0;
    I2C1CONbits.RSEN = 0;      
    I2C1CONbits.SEN = 0;


// starting the module
I2C1CONbits.I2CEN = 1;

// setting the START CONDITION
I2C1CONbits.SEN = 1;
```

There is no response. The Start Condition is not executed. The I2C pheripheral is on NON-remappable pins. Whole TrisD register (pin 43 = D9, pin 44 = D10) is set as input (after reset). The pins has pull-ups (3.3 V, 4.7 kOhm). I have also tried to set corresponding bit in ODCD to 1 (digital pin), and 0 (open drain).

Have I missed something?
Microcontroller is working fine (UART, PWM, reference clock, ADC, ...).

I would appriciate any guidance.

Comment: Try it by hand ...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZYMrcHm91s

Comment: I2C1CONbits.PEN doesn't initiate a start condition - that's for a stop. Use *SEN* for a start.

Comment: Thank you, mistake is corrected but the problem remains

Comment: Does your I2C1CON.BCL bit ever get set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the hard way.

Write the test routine for sending start or stop bits and put it in a while loop.

Your main code will look like this.

```
main
{
initialize i2c();//Configure the I2C module in this function
while(1)
{
 i2c_send(); //Learn how the I2C transmits data and send the data   accordingly.
}

}
```

> Now take an oscilloscope and observe the wave forms.

If have not messed up with configurations or initializations you will see the magic waves.

Comment: That is the first thing I have tried. I already coded my own functions for filling I2C1TMR (transmission register) and checking, whether data are send and conditions executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XC16, you can `#include <i2c.h>` and try using the `OpenI2C1()` library call to do the dirty work of configuring the peripheral instead of writing directly to the SFR.

Here is code I use to open I2C1 as a master:

```
#include <i2c.h>

u16Clk = 39; // specified by OP

OpenI2C1(
    I2C1_ON &
    I2C1_IDLE_CON &
    I2C1_7BIT_ADD &
    I2C1_STR_EN &
    I2C1_SLW_DIS &
    I2C1_GCALL_DIS &
    I2C1_SM_EN &
    I2C1_IPMI_DIS,
    u16Clk
);
```

Once it's open, you can see if it works by sending a start, sending an arbitrary (non-reserved address), then send a stop (while scoping the lines).

```
StartI2C1();
MasterWriteI2C1(data);
MasterWaitForIntrI2C1();
StopI2C1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers.

The module is definitely dead. The code works for I2C2 module just fine.